# Can't use wifi after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: wireless, lenovo, 20.04, blacklist

Today is a day that I have been looking forward to for a while now.  I upgraded my machine to 20.04, but I have run into a bit of a snag.

I have been running Ubuntu on an SSD on my Lenovo Legion y530 (i7-8750h, GTX 1050 ti) for about a year now.  When I originally installed Ubuntu, I was having the usual trouble with Nvidia graphics, but also wifi.  I followed these instructions when I first set it up.

In browsing those instructions, you will find that I had to `sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop` and then add `ideapad_laptop` to my blacklist. When I was updating Ubuntu today, I was asked if I wanted to replace my `blacklist.conf` file, and I selected to keep the original, as I was worried that that would make the transition to 20.04 more difficult.

After booting in to 20.04, it has become apparent that I may have not selected the right choice, as I do not have wifi capability at this time.  I'm not sure if I have to blacklist something else, or if there is something else that I need to do to my blacklist entirely.

For the time being, I can use a wired connection, but I would like to figure this out soon.  Please let me know if you have any ideas as to how to fix this, or if I could offer further clarification.  Thank you.

EDIT: Tags and link

EDIT: As requested, this is the output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

EDIT: Corrected output when I run lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` without using USB tethering on my phone

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT:  Output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlp7s0
   version: 00
   serial: d8:9c:67:34:80:c5
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-26-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: iomemory:ffffffff0-fffffffef irq:146 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff


 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: enp8s0
   version: 15
   serial: 8c:16:45:dc:37:4d
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
   resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Thank you, see above

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsmod | grep 8822`

Comment: That gave me no result.  I am also realizing now that I have made a a slight mistake.  When I entered `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`, I was using wifi-tethering on my phone.  When I disconnect my phone from my PC and enter that command, I only get results for bluetooth.  I will edit the post to reflect that.  So sorry for the confusion. @Jeremy31 @Pilot6

Comment: I am not sure why using a phone to tether would change the results.  Reboot and run the commands again

Comment: @Jeremy31 I rebooted my system and ran the commands again but got no new results.  I am able to open wifi settings, but there are no connections listed

Comment: Please check BIOS settings and see if wifi/WLAN is enabled

Comment: @Jeremy31 WLAN is enabled in my BIOS

Comment: for some reason there isn't a lot to work with here. Would you be so kind as to [edit] the output of `sudo lshw -C network` into your question? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek No worries, see my edit.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the terrible world of the new kernel and Realtek Wi-Fi... It broke some cards that were already working (like mine RTL8723ae). Some people can solve it using https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 (not my case). Just follow the instructions of github to install the drivers.

Comment: Thank you!  It appears that this worked for me!  My PC used RTL8822BE and all I had to do was follow the instructions on GitHub.  Thanks again!

Comment: @GovernorDynamic No need to thank, glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm already have same problem for 19.10.

You should find driver for your chipset

In my case, rtl8812au

https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au-5.6.4.2

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for resolving this issue on my Lenovo Legion Y530:

#### Section for RTL8822BE and RTL8822CE

The drivers for these devices are found in the rtw88 branch. To get the codes, you need to do the following:

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
cd rtw88
make
sudo make install
```

When your kernel changes, then you need to do the following:

```
cd ~/rtw88
git pull
make
sudo make install
```

Remember, this MUST be done whenever you get a new kernel - no exceptions.

These drivers will not build for kernels older than 4.14. If you are using a kernel newer than 5.2,
I suggest that you use the driver built into the kernel!

Follow the readme for other versions: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

Comment: Exactly why we needed the output of `sudo lshw -C network` ! Congratulations on the solve and an upvote for self answering.