# Activation of Network connection failed Ubuntu 20.04 Lenovo Y530

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I have this problem about a year now. System had Windows 10(by default). I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and after a while i started getting these messages of Network connection failed. To get it around i booted first from windows, and then from Ubuntu and everything was fine. Now I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in position of 18.04 and the problem remains! I followed every troubleshooting tip I could get but No luck at all. e.g: [Can't use wifi after upgrading to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229937/cant-use-wifi-after-upgrading-to-20-04). I am not very familiar with wifi settings, adapters or hardware troubleshooting of network devices etc. What should i do?

`$lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$lspci -nnk | grep 0280  -A3
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad E595 [17aa:b023]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822be
    Kernel modules: rtw_8822be
```

```
$sudo dmesg | grep -e rtw -e 07:00
```

```
[    0.312590] pci 0000:07:00.0: [10ec:b822] type 00 class 0x028000
[    0.312733] pci 0000:07:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0x4000-0x40ff]
[    0.312849] pci 0000:07:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xa4300000-0xa430ffff 64bit]
[    0.313345] pci 0000:07:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.313346] pci 0000:07:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    4.124095] rtw_core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    4.124575] rtw_core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    4.129813] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: Firmware version 27.2.0, H2C version 13
[    4.156586] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: use rfe_def[5]
[    4.402224] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0 wlp7s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6.567004] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: start vif 80:2b:f9:1b:00:65 on port 0
[   11.921675] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: sta 44:ff:ba:0a:e4:14 joined with macid 0
[   36.975365] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 8 at /home/mypc/Programs/rtw88/pci.c:1308 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   36.975366] Modules linked in: ccm cmac nvidia_uvm(O) algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm nvidia(PO) crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper rapl snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) rtw_pci(OE) rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event intel_cstate i915 mac80211 snd_rawmidi uvcvideo serio_raw btusb intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof snd_seq efi_pstore btrtl videobuf2_vmalloc cfg80211 btbcm drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device snd_timer *
[   36.975400] Workqueue: phy0 rtw_watch_dog_work [rtw_core]
[   36.975402] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   36.975410]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[   36.975414]  rtw_leave_lps+0x86/0x1e0 [rtw_core]
[   36.975417]  rtw_watch_dog_work+0x1c5/0x240 [rtw_core]
[   36.975426] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[   36.978645] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   37.120335] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
[   37.123467] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   37.126604] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   37.129731] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   37.132880] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   37.136015] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   37.139138] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   37.139491] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 8 at /home/mypc/Programs/rtw88/pci.c:1308 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   37.139492] Modules linked in: *
[   37.139619] Workqueue: phy0 rtw_watch_dog_work [rtw_core]
[   37.139627] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   37.139666]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[   37.139685]  rtw_enter_lps+0xe2/0x120 [rtw_core]
[   37.139698]  rtw_watch_dog_work+0x216/0x240 [rtw_core]
[   37.139739] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[   37.977471] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 8 at /home/mypc/Programs/rtw88/pci.c:1308 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   37.977473] Modules linked in: *
[   37.977658] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   37.977698]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[   37.977718]  rtw_leave_lps+0x86/0x1e0 [rtw_core]
[   37.977733]  rtw_ops_config+0xc6/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[   37.977979] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[   37.981116] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   38.121815] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
[   38.124946] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   38.128078] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   38.736176] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[0]
[   38.736256] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[1]
[   38.736331] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[2]
[   38.736405] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[3]
[   38.736480] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[5]
[   38.736554] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[6]
[   38.739754] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   38.739763] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: sta 44:ff:ba:0a:e4:14 with macid 0 left
[   38.743259] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   38.743332] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[0]
[   38.743399] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[1]
[   38.743466] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[2]
[   38.743533] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[3]
[   38.743600] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[5]
[   38.743666] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[6]
[   38.746784] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to send h2c command
[   40.798912] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   40.799206] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 8 at /home/mypc/Programs/rtw88/pci.c:1308 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   40.799206] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac nvidia_uvm(O) algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm nvidia(PO) crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper rapl snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) rtw_pci(OE) rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event intel_cstate i915 mac80211 snd_rawmidi uvcvideo serio_raw btusb intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof snd_seq efi_pstore btrtl videobuf2_vmalloc cfg80211 btbcm drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device snd_timer
[   40.799254] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   40.799263]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[   40.799267]  ? rtw_core_stop+0xda/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[   40.799270]  rtw_enter_ips+0x3e/0x50 [rtw_core]
[   40.799273]  rtw_ops_config+0xd3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[   40.799388] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[   40.799545] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[0]
[   40.799634] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[1]
[   40.799701] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[2]
[   40.799790] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[3]
[   40.799874] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[5]
[   40.799963] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[6]
[   40.902509] WARNING: CPU: 8 PID: 853 at /home/mypc/Programs/rtw88/pci.c:1308 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   40.902510] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac nvidia_uvm(O) algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm nvidia(PO) crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper rapl snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) rtw_pci(OE) rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event intel_cstate i915 mac80211 snd_rawmidi uvcvideo serio_raw btusb intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof snd_seq efi_pstore btrtl videobuf2_vmalloc cfg80211 btbcm drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device snd_timer
[   40.902621] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   40.902656]  rtw_pci_link_ps+0x54/0x90 [rtw_pci]
[   40.902674]  rtw_leave_ips+0x1f/0x80 [rtw_core]
[   40.902687]  rtw_ops_config+0xa3/0xe0 [rtw_core]
[   40.903198] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to read ASPM, ret=-5
[   42.942411] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   42.942416] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: mac power on failed
[   42.942417] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to power on mac
[   42.942418] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: leave idle state failed
[   42.942554] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to leave ips state
[   42.942556] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to leave idle state
[   42.942637] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[0]
[   42.942703] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[1]
[   42.942769] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[2]
[   42.942836] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[3]
[   42.942902] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[5]
[   42.942969] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[6]
[   42.943042] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[0]
[   42.943109] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[1]
[   42.943175] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[2]
[   42.943242] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[3]
[   42.943309] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[5]
[   42.943375] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[6]
[   46.873672] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[0]
[   46.873774] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[1]
[   46.873841] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[2]
[   46.873910] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[3]
[   46.873981] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[5]
[   46.874048] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: timed out to flush pci tx ring[6]
[   48.891750] rtw_8822be 0000:07:00.0: failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
[   48.892064] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 8 at /home/mypc/Programs/rtw88/pci.c:1308 rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
[   48.892064] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac nvidia_uvm(O) algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm nvidia(PO) crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper rapl snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm rtw_8822be(OE) rtw_8822b(OE) rtw_pci(OE) rtw_core(OE) snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event intel_cstate i915 mac80211 snd_rawmidi uvcvideo serio_raw btusb intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof snd_seq efi_pstore btrtl videobuf2_vmalloc cfg80211 btbcm drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device snd_timer
[   48.892134] RIP: 0010:rtw_dbi_read8.constprop.0+0xaa/0xc0 [rtw_pci]
...
```

I pasted a part of this because it's too big for ask ubuntu

Comment: "I booted first from windows, and then from Ubuntu and everything was fine." Could this be the problem?  https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?p=iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Unfortunately not in my case. I have already disabled fast boot from windows.

Comment: May we please see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280  -A3` Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 I just added it.

Comment: When you boot and there is *no* wireless, please run and post: `sudo dmesg | grep -e rtw -e 07:00` Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 I pasted a part of it cause it's too big.